# How to swap the position of two <path> elements inside an SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an `<svg>` included in my HTML file with a bunch of `<path>` elements.

My desired behavior is to be able to randomly shuffle the positioning of the `<path>` elements, and then to subsequently sort them back into their proper position.

Example: if I have 3 `<path>`s at positions 1, 2, and 3. For the shuffle functionality, I move path 1 to position 3, path 2 to position 1, and path 3 to position 2. Then I do some kind of visual sort (e.g. insertion sort), where I swap two `<path>`s' positions at a time until the `<path>`s are back in their proper place and the SVG looks normal again.

If these were "normal" HTML elements I would just set the x and y properties, but based on my research `<path>` elements don't have those properties, so I've resorted to using the `transform: translate(x y)`.

With my current approach, the first swap works fine. But any subsequent swaps get way out of whack, and go too far in both directions.

If I'm just swapping two `<path>`s back and forth, I can get it to work consistently by keeping track of which element is in which position (e.g. `elem.setAttribute('currPos', otherElem.id)`), and when `currPos == currElem.id`, setting `transform: translate(0 0)`, but when I start adding more elements, they end up moving to places where there previously wasn’t a `<path>` element.

My current code is below. For some reason the CSS transition isn’t working properly here but it works elsewhere (edit: it works fine on desktop just not on my phone)

```js
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function getPos(elem) {
  let rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = rect.left + (rect.right - rect.left) / 2;
  let y = rect.top + (rect.bottom - rect.top) / 2;
  return [x, y];
}

async function swap(e1, e2, delayMs = 3000) {
  let e1Pos = getPos(e1);
  let e2Pos = getPos(e2);
  console.log(e1Pos, e2Pos);
  e2.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${e1Pos[0]-e2Pos[0]}, ${e1Pos[1]-e2Pos[1]})`);
  e1.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${e2Pos[0]-e1Pos[0]}, ${e2Pos[1]-e1Pos[1]})`);
  if (delayMs) {
    await delay(delayMs);
  }
}

let blackSquare = document.getElementById('black-square');
let redSquare = document.getElementById('red-square');

swap(blackSquare, redSquare)
  .then(() => swap(blackSquare, redSquare))
  .then(() => swap(blackSquare, redSquare));
```

```css
* {
  position: absolute;
}

path {
  transition: transform 3s
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="black-square" d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" fill="black" />
  <path id="red-square" d="M 130 70 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80" fill="red" />
  <path id="green-square" d="M 20 120 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Comment: An easy way to do this is to define all your paths at the origin inside a defs element and then display them using multiple use elements - which do have x and y positions. It doesn't stop you from having to keep track of each object's position through multiple swaps though - that's irreducible.

Comment: Okay just looked up defs and use elements. That does look promising, though somewhat tedious (the SVG I’m using right now is of the human skeleton and has many many <path>s). Probably less work overall than trying to get it to work with transform+translate alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by applying **multiple translate transformations.**

Lets say, the red square should be positioned at the black square position:

```
<path transform="translate(-130 -70) translate(10 10)" id="redSquare" d="M 130 70 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80" fill="red" ></path>
```

`translate(-130 -70)`  negates the square's original x,y offset and moves this element to the svg's coordinate origin.
The second transformation `translate(10 10)` will move this element to the black square's position.

```js
const paths = document.querySelectorAll("path");

function shuffleEls(paths) {
  /**
  * get current positions and save to data attribute
  * skip this step if data attribute is already set
  */
  if(!paths[0].getAttribute('data-pos')){
    paths.forEach((path) => {
      posToDataAtt(path);
    });
  }
  // shuffle path element array
  const shuffledPaths = shuffleArr([...paths]);
  for (let i = 0; i < shuffledPaths.length; i += 1) {
    let len = shuffledPaths.length;
    //let el1 = i>0 ? shuffledPaths[i-1] : shuffledPaths[len-1] ;
    let el1 = shuffledPaths[i];
    let el2 = paths[i];
    copyPosFrom(el1, el2);
  }
}

function posToDataAtt(el) {
  let bb = el.getBBox();
  let [x, y, width, height] = [bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height].map((val) => {
    return +val.toFixed(2);
  });
  el.dataset.pos = [x, y].join(" ");
}

function copyPosFrom(el1, el2) {
  let [x1, y1] = el1.dataset.pos.split(" ").map((val) => {
    return +val;
  });
  let [x2, y2] = el2.dataset.pos.split(" ").map((val) => {
    return +val;
  });
  /**
   * original position is negated by negative x/y offsets
   * new position copied from 2nd element
   */
  el1.setAttribute(
    "transform",
    `translate(-${x1} -${y1}) translate(${x2} ${y2})`
  );
}

function shuffleArr(arr) {
  const newArr = arr.slice();
  for (let i = newArr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [newArr[i], newArr[rand]] = [newArr[rand], newArr[i]];
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

```css
svg{
  border:1px solid red;
}

path{
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="shuffleEls(paths)">shuffleAll()</button>
</p>

<svg width="500" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="blackSquare" d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" fill="black" />
  <path id="redSquare" d="M 130 70 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80" fill="red" />
  <path id="greenSquare" d="M 20 120 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80" fill="green" />
  <path id="purpleSquare" d="M 250 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80" fill="purple" />
</svg>
```

#### How it works

1. `shuffleEls()` gets each path's position via `getBBox()` and saves x and y  coordinates to a data attribute
2. We shuffle the path element array
3. each path inherits the position from it's shuffled counterpart

swap positions:

```
let el1 = shuffledPaths[i];  
let el2 = paths[i];  
copyPosFrom(el1, el2);
```

#### Update: include previous transformations

If a `<path>` element is already transformed (e.g rotated), you probably want to retain it.

```js
const paths = document.querySelectorAll(".pathToshuffle");


function revertShuffling(paths) {
  if (paths[0].getAttribute('data-pos')) {
    paths.forEach((path) => {
      copyPosFrom(path, path);
    });
  }
}

//shuffleEls(paths)
function shuffleEls(paths) {
  /**
   * get current positions and save to data attribute
   * skip this step if data attribute is already set
   */
  if (!paths[0].getAttribute('data-pos')) {
    paths.forEach((path) => {
      posToDataAtt(path);
    });
  }
  // shuffle path element array
  const shuffledPaths = shuffleArr([...paths]);
  let shuffledElCount = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < shuffledPaths.length; i += 1) {
    let el1 = shuffledPaths[i];
    let el2 = paths[i];
    shuffledElCount += copyPosFrom(el1, el2);
  }
  // repeat shuffling if result is identical to previous one
  if (shuffledElCount < 1) {
    shuffleEls(paths);
  }
}

function posToDataAtt(el) {
  let bb = el.getBBox();
  let [x, y, width, height] = [bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height].map((val) => {
    return +val.toFixed(2);
  });
  // include other transformations
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
  let matrix = style.transform != 'none' ? style.transform : '';
  el.dataset.pos = [x + width / 2, y + height / 2, matrix].join("|");
}

function copyPosFrom(el1, el2) {
  let [x1, y1, matrix1] = el1.dataset.pos.split("|");
  let [x2, y2, matrix2] = el2.dataset.pos.split("|");
  /**
   * original position is negated by negative x/y offsets
   * new position copied from 2nd element
   */
  let transformAtt = `translate(-${x1} -${y1}) translate(${x2} ${y2}) ${matrix1}`;
  // compare previous transformations to prevent identical/non-shuffled results
  let transFormChange = el1.getAttribute('transform') != transformAtt ? 1 : 0;
  el1.setAttribute("transform", transformAtt);
  return transFormChange;
}

function shuffleArr(arr) {
  let newArr = arr.slice();
  for (let i = newArr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [newArr[i], newArr[rand]] = [newArr[rand], newArr[i]];
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

path {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="shuffleEls(paths)">shuffleAll()</button>
  <button onclick="revertShuffling(paths)">revertShuffling()</button>
</p>

<svg width="500" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="pathToshuffle" id="blackSquare" d="M 20 30 h 60 v 40 h -60 z" fill="#999" />
  <path class="pathToshuffle" id="redSquare" d="M 130 70 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80" fill="red" />
  <path class="pathToshuffle"  id="greenSquare" d="M 20 120 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80" fill="green" />
  <path class="pathToshuffle" transform="rotate(45 275 35)"  id="purpleSquare" d="M 250 10 h 50 v 50 h -50 v -50" fill="purple" />
  
  <path id="bg" d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10z
                   M 130 70 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80z
                   M 20 120 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80z
                   M 250 10 h 50 v 50 h -50 v -50z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="1 2"/>
  
</svg>
```

We can append a `matrix()` to the data attribute.
If paths have different sizes or aspect ratios, you can also set centered x/y coordinates according the the actual bounding box.
This way, all shuffled elements will be positioned around the same center points.

```
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
  let matrix = style.transform!='none' ? style.transform : '';
  el.dataset.pos = [x+width/2, y+height/2, matrix].join("|");
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you for this. I ended up using a variation of this approach. Just fyi your swap example code only moves one element rather than swapping the two elements positions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is is easier to keep track of the positions if all the `<path>` elements have the same starting point (so, the same distance to 0,0) and then use transform/translate to position them. You can use elements transform matrix to find the position.

```js
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function getPos(elem) {
  let x = elem.transform.baseVal[0].matrix.e;
  let y = elem.transform.baseVal[0].matrix.f;
  return [x,y];
}

async function swap(e1, e2, delayMs = 3000) {
  let e1Pos = getPos(e1);
  let e2Pos = getPos(e2);
  e2.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${e1Pos[0]} ${e1Pos[1]})`);
  e1.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${e2Pos[0]} ${e2Pos[1]})`);
  if (delayMs) {
    await delay(delayMs);
  }
}

let blackSquare = document.getElementById('black-square');
let redSquare = document.getElementById('red-square');
let greenSquare = document.getElementById('green-square');

swap(blackSquare, redSquare)
  .then(() => swap(blackSquare, redSquare))
  .then(() => swap(blackSquare, greenSquare));
```

```css
path {
  transition: transform 3s
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 400" width="500"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="black-square" d="M 0 0 H 80 V 80 H 0 Z"
    fill="black" transform="translate(200 50)" />
  <path id="red-square" d="M 0 0 H 80 V 80 H 0 Z"
    fill="red" transform="translate(50 20)" />
  <path id="green-square" d="M 0 0 H 80 V 80 H 0 Z"
    fill="green" transform="translate(100 120)" />
</svg>
```